# Replacing Discourse and Slack with a single platform?

Tags: web-apps, chat, communication, forum

(Initially posted in [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2921) but it was recommended I post here too.)

**TL;DR: Are there tools/platforms that can replace both Discourse (forums for end users) and Slack (chat for developers) at once for a small open source organization?**

We're a small open source organization that started in 2009. Originally we had forums for end users (based on Drupal), a public mailing list for developers and Skype/Hangout for chats.

These last few years we've been using a combination of forums (Discourse) for end users and real time chat (Slack) for the development team.

**When we introduced it to the community in December 2016, Slack had a transformative effect on our developers community** and allowed the team to grow and organize in ways that, I believe, wouldn't have been possible with just forums, mailing lists and Skype.

Unfortunately Slack is way too expensive for us, and as a non-US organization we aren't eligible for a free standard plan. We're looking into what could replace Slack and are investigating Mattermost, Discord, Telegram and a few others. We've quickly discussed IRC but ruled it out due to the lack of features.

**We're now wondering if we could also unify Discourse and Slack**: The division between end users and developers has always felt a bit artificial and we often end up posting forums links to Slack to make sure developers are aware of our users' questions and feedback.

**What we value in Slack:**

- Modern UI/UX, intuitive look-and-feel, good defaults
- The instantaneous nature of conversations is very important to us
- Organizing discussions in channels, spontaneously creating custom-tailored groups to discuss specific issues, etc.
- Easily sharing files with other developers
- Sharing code snippets with syntax highlighting...

**What we find frustrating in Slack:**

- Conversations being readable by Slack members only
- Users needing to be invited to join (although we worked around this with [Slackin](https://github.com/rauchg/slackin))
- Hard to find old conversations or old files
- Lack of members management (e.g. removing users that never logged in after joining, users that haven't logged in in years)

**What we like in Discourse:**

- Modern UI/UX, intuitive look-and-feel, good defaults
- Users don't need to setup an account to ask a quick question
- Forums in general: clear topics, easier to follow, easier to search
- Lots of tools to manage members

**What we don't like in Discourse:**

- Doesn't allow real time conversations

**Are there tools that combine the strengths of forums and team chats? Any advice on how we could organize ourselves on a budget (we can't afford to pay for Slack)?**

Open source would be ideal but not a requirement. We would be happy to pay a modest monthly fee to have it hosted for us.

Comment: Define what you are willing to pay, and platform?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow If you're referring to the word "platform" in the question's title, I mean in the sense of application. Regarding what we're willing to pay, it really depends on the service but as a fully volunteers operation we have no income and limited budget so around $60/month seems like a reasonable upper bound.

Comment: Thanks, $60/m sounds reasonable. Do  you need any integratation? I *strongly* recommend you look into Nextcloud's planner, task and chat - ticks all my needs and I dare say yours.